# hybrid app using Ionic + TypeScript + Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript

Hey I had developed hybrid app using Ionic + Typescript + Angular.
I used beta version of Ionic lib, it was running fine, but when i update my ionic lib beta version to 1.0.0 version, then i got following error from ionic.bundle.js

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=AppCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>   minErr/<@file:///E:/Yogesh/my_task/myApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8763:12
>   assertArg@file:///E:/Yogesh/my_task/myApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10280:1
>   assertArgFn@file:///E:/Yogesh/my_task/myApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10290:1
>   $ControllerProvider/this.$get

**AppCtrl.ts**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[]);

class AppCtrl{

    constructor($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout)
    {
         // Form data for the login modal
          $scope.loginData = {};

          // Create the login modal that we will use later
          $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
            scope: $scope
          }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
          });

          // Triggered in the login modal to close it
          $scope.closeLogin = function() {
            $scope.modal.hide();
          };

          // Open the login modal
          $scope.login = function() {
            $scope.modal.show();
          };

          // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
          $scope.doLogin = function() {
            console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.closeLogin();
            }, 1000);
          };
    }
}
```

I have written my controller in Typescript and after compile it in to js and then  used in my app.

**App.js**

in app.js i inject my controller like following:

```
angular.module('starter', ['starter.controllers', 'ionic')
```

Comment: Try to add export modifier to class declaration http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-export-

Comment: If i used export then also i got error

Comment: module starter.controllers {


 export class AppCtrl {


  constructor($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

                  }
       }

Comment: Try to move declaration of class before declaration of controller angular.module('starter.controllers').controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl)

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my problem-

module DemoNS {
export class AppCtrl {

```
constructor($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

//your stuff

}
```

}
}

angular.module('starter.controllers',[]).controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope","$ionicModal","$timeout", DemoNS.AppCtrl]);

Answer (score 0):

just make a reference to your controller in the angular way as follows and you're good to go :-)

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers')
  .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);
```